# How to inject a RestTemplate into another class and test it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I currently have a service class like this:

```
@Service
public class CarService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public CarService () {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }
    ...
}
```

that is being called by an application runner class like this:

```
@Component
public class CarRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    CarService carService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
           ...
           Cars cars = carService.getCars();
           ...
```

I would like to get rid of the `restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` as it is causing me problems when I'm mocking tests.

My test class is like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CarServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarService carService = new CarService();

    @Test
    public void testCars() {
        ...
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                    RequestEntity.get(new URI(uri))
                                    .headers(headers).build(),
                                     Cars.class))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCars, HttpStatus.OK));
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to avoid this dependency?

Comment: Have you tried removing the constructor and adding `@Autowired` to the `restTemplate` field?

Comment: Yes, it still fails with `"this.restTemplate" is null`  in the tests; Considering this change, the application itself will also fail when it runs, as it was relying on the `= new RestTemplate();` to have it first instantiated.

Comment: Of course, you would need to define a `RestTemplate` bean in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of field injection, use constructor injection as follows:

```java
@Service
public class CarService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public CarService (RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    ...
}
```

Spring will understand that a `RestTemplate` bean is needed to create a `CarService` and will inject it via constructor (assuming you have a `RestTemplate` bean created elsewhere, most probably via auto-configuration).

Then in the test, you can remove `new CarService();` as follows:

```java
public class CarServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarService carService;

    @Before 
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCars() {
        ...
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                    RequestEntity.get(new URI(uri))
                                    .headers(headers).build(),
                                     Cars.class))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCars, HttpStatus.OK));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it. Basically, I removed  `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and replaced it with the method annotated with `@Before`.